# Azure File Share user specific access permissions

Tags: windows, azure, acl, fileshare

I want to implement Azure File share for my network, but I can't find any possibility to set up user specific access permissions. There are some pre-built groups, which are for no use in this scenario, but [I found a MS page recommending using Windows ACLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-ad-ds-configure-permissions), but how can I proceed with setting user specific permissions, when I want to assign different permissions to different folders/files to different users, who are part of the same Administrator group in AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! You just need to remove permissions inheritance and remove all inherited security groups/users permissions and add your own users or custom defined groups.